# Server farm configuration resources

Tags: server-farm, farm-setup

Since making a shift from front end development/branding to solution development, I have had a lot of tasks that involve at least a beginners understanding of farm configuration and server basics.

Ive seen that many different services and applications relying on their own dedicated server, some virtual, some not. Im sure theres no one size fits all farm architecture but I would like to understand how to choose what works best.

Does anyone know of a good book or resource I can use to begin to wrap my head around server configuration in the context of SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from this article about an architecture design:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff601871.aspx